# android getMenuInflater() in a fragment subclass - cannot resolve method

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-menu

I am trying to inflate a menu in a class that inherits the `Fragment` class.
Here is my `OnCreateOptionsMenu()` method -

```
@Override
public boolean OnCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.forecastfragment, menu) ;
    return true;
}
```

This raises the following error:

> Cannot resolve method 'getMenuInflater()'

I tried :

```
MenuInflater inflater = getActivity().getMenuInflater();
```

but then Android Studio highlights `@Override` in red and states:

> Method does not override method from its superclass

I also tried to create a `getMenuInflater` method in the same class and have it return `new MenuInflater(this)`

```
public MenuInflater getMenuInflater() {
    return new MenuInflater(this);
}
```

but then the following error is thrown :

> error: incompatible types: ForecastFragment cannot be converted to
> Context
>
> error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

What do I do?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The signature of your `onCreateOptionsMenu` doesn't look right. Take a look at the docs [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu,%20android.view.MenuInflater))

Take a look this code

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);//Make sure you have this line of code.
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // TODO Add your menu entries here
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

Comment: While the method resolves correctly, I still can't get the `method does not override from a supertype` to go away.

Answer (score 5):

In your fragment class add:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.[IDMENU], menu) ;
}
```

Where [IDMENU] is the XML name of your menu.

Next you need to add inside onCreate or onCreateView method this:

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this code:

```
@Override
public boolean OnCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.forecastfragment, menu) ;
    final MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.forecastID);
}
```

where forecastID is the ID of the item in the menu forcastfragment.xml.
Also add `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` in your `OnCreateView()` so that the fragment will call the method.

As a side, it's standard practice to include the word 'menu' in your menu file names such as 'forecastfragment_menu.xml'. It avoids confusion.

Answer (score 1):

- According to [API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu,%20android.view.MenuInflater)) not `overriding` a [`super`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu,%20android.view.MenuInflater)) method.
- You are not calling the correct method `inflate`.

You must use it in this way:

```
@Override
public boolean OnCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.forecastfragment, menu);
    return true;
}
```