# Bug: exchange between fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-toolbar

- I will try to explain at best, adding references and images in which
  I think it is difficult to explain in words the error I encountered.
  Working with the fragments  and the Navigation Drawer I've faced this
  bug:

[image]
[image]

- From time to time, when I open the navigation menu, the previous
  fragment is duplicated or loaded again. This thing is completely
  random, without a precise scheme. The only thing that seems
  connected is the RecyclerView and the Navigation Drawer.
- Just because I do not know where I'm wrong, write in the comments if you 
  need something, code or other information and from time to time I'll add it 
  to the original question.
- I am not receiving any errors and to help both me and you add some code and 
  images of how that fragment is loaded without bugs:

[image]
[image]

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    Fragment fragment = null;
    Class aclass = null;
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    Intent intentOperatore = getIntent();
    String mParamOperatore = intentOperatore.getStringExtra(ARG_PARAM_OPERATORE);
    boolean navigation = Boolean.FALSE;
    boolean intent = Boolean.FALSE;
    boolean scan = Boolean.FALSE;
    boolean exit = Boolean.FALSE;

    try{
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.nav_home:
                aclass = HomeFragment.class;
                fragment = (Fragment) aclass.newInstance();
                args.putString(ARG_PARAM_OPERATORE,mParamOperatore);
                fragment.setArguments(args);
                navigation = Boolean.TRUE;
                break;
            case R.id.nav_procedura_immobiliare:
                aclass = FiltroFragment.class;
                fragment = (Fragment) aclass.newInstance();
                args.putString(ARG_CHECK_CLASS,"immobiliari");
                fragment.setArguments(args);
                navigation = Boolean.TRUE;
                break;
            case R.id.nav_procedura_mobiliare:
                aclass = FiltroFragment.class;
                fragment = (Fragment) aclass.newInstance();
                args.putString(ARG_CHECK_CLASS,"mobiliari");
                fragment.setArguments(args);
                navigation = Boolean.TRUE;
                break;
            case R.id.nav_localizza_procedura:
                aclass = LocalizzaActivity.class;
                intent = Boolean.TRUE;
                break;
            case R.id.nav_ricognizione:
                aclass = RicognizioneFragment.class;
                fragment = (Fragment) aclass.newInstance();
                args.putString(ARG_PARAM_RICOGNIZIONE,""); //TODO: Add param here.
                fragment.setArguments(args);
                navigation = Boolean.TRUE;
                break;
            case R.id.nav_qrcode:
                scan = Boolean.TRUE;
                break;
            case R.id.nav_exit:
                exit = Boolean.TRUE;
                break;
        }

        if(navigation) { // Navigazione per i fragment
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, fragment).commit();
        } if(intent) { // Navigazione per le activity
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),aclass);
            myIntent.putExtra(ARG_PARAM_OPERATORE,mParamOperatore);
            startActivity(myIntent);
            finish();
        } if(scan) {
            new MVBarcodeScanner.Builder()
                    .setScanningMode(MVBarcodeScanner.ScanningMode.SINGLE_AUTO)
                    .setFormats(Barcode.QR_CODE)
                    .build()
                    .launchScanner(MainActivity.this,REQ_CODE);
        } if(exit) { // Navigazione per l'uscita
            MaterialDialog dialog = new MaterialDialog.Builder(this)
                    .title(R.string.title_exit)
                    .content(R.string.summary_exit)
                    .positiveText(R.string.action_exit)
                    .onPositive(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(MaterialDialog dialog, DialogAction which) {
                            finish();
                        }
                    })
                    .negativeText(R.string.action_no)
                    .show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(this.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

**Edit:**

- I also notice another thing that recycling is not the only thing to 
  duplicate. There is also the toolbar item that is duplicated:

[image]
[image]

**Edit 2:**
 - I've added the onCreateOptionsMenu and some code that i run in the 
   onCreateView:

```
 @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        //inflater.inflate(R.menu.procedura_menu_action, menu);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.procedura_menu_list, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }
```

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_procedure_list, container, false);

    Context context = view.getContext();
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rvProcedure);

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);

    mAdapter = new ProcedureAdapter(context,procedure,this);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(context,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    actionModeCallback = new ActionModeCallback();

    Toolbar toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle(getString(R.string.title_lista_procedure) + " " + mCheckClass);
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_navigator);
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

            if(drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            } else {
                drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }
        }
    });

    floatingActionButton = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fab_new);
    floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            args.putString(ARG_PARAM_TIPOLOGIA,mParamTipologia); //Passa la procedura selezionata se siamo in modifica
            args.putString(ARG_PARAM_PROCEDURA,new Gson().toJson(procedure.get(lastPosition)));

            if(actionMode != null) //Leva la selezione se è presente, prima di passare ad un'altro fragment.
                enableActionMode(lastPosition);

            try {
                if ((getActivity()) != null) {
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager();
                    Class fragmentClass = ProceduraFragment.class;
                    Fragment fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
                    fragment.setArguments(args);
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
                }
            } catch (java.lang.InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

   //TODO: Implements here the load logic for procedure.
    if(mParamProcedura != null && !(procedure.size() > 0)) {
        procedure.add(mParamProcedura);
    } else if(!(procedure.size() > 0)) {
        refreshList(AlphaMAS.getData());
    }

    return view;
}
```

Comment: as a dirty and quick workaround: It should be enough to set some background to your fragments so the second (unneeded) fragment is just not visible

Comment: Just add `android:background="@color/white"` in your fragment xml file

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko  i will try it instantly, i'm gonna update you right away

Comment: @ChiragSavsani I've edited the question, there are also the toolbar item that is duplicated.

Answer (score 2):

Why create a new fragment instance everytime? Try something like this:

```
if (fragment == null)
fragment = (Fragment) aclass.newInstance();
```

Comment: Can you be more specific, i don't wanna mess up everything.

Comment: The thing is, i declare every time that `Fragment fragment = null` so that `if (fragment == null)` is always true.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

Set background to both of your xml file's parent layout.

```
android:background="@color/background_color_which_you_want"
```

**Edit 1:**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.procedura_menu_list, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: I've edited the question, there are also the toolbar item that is duplicated.

Comment: @G.Ciardini, post your `onCreateOptionMenu()` method code.

Comment: @SagarZala I've added also what i'm doing in the onCreateView

Comment: Try to remove `setHasOptionMenu(true)` from your `onCreateView()` method

Comment: @SagarZala The apps crash, by saying: "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views."

Comment: @SagarZala I've fixed the crash by myself, but if i remove `setHasOptionMenu(true)`, the toolbar don't display my item

Comment: @SagarZala i cant use `getMenuInflater()` because i'm in a fragment, take a look at this [android-getmenuinflater-in-a-fragment-subclass-cannot-resolve-method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30847096/android-getmenuinflater-in-a-fragment-subclass-cannot-resolve-method)

Comment: try `getActivity().getMenuInflater()`

Comment: @SagarZala if use `public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` with `getActivity().getMenuInflater()` I get `method does not override method from its superclass`

Answer (score 0):

Inside your layout in both `Fragment`s use this :

```
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
```

Comment: Can you explain where should i put this two attributes and why this should work?

Comment: Inside your fragment XML in your main container use those 2 lines for example :   <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
           >
and its because even if u give the layout background color you still have the other xml layout in background so if you have button in back and you click on the foreground layout it will active the button in back

Comment: I've tryed your possible solution but it isn't working.